# (Deep) copying an array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most efficient way to clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

I need to copy an (ordered, not associative) array of objects. I'm using jQuery. I initially tried

```
jquery.extend({}, myArray)
```

but, naturally, this gives me back an object, where I need an array (really love jquery.extend, by the way).

So, what's the best way to copy an array?

Comment: If you don't want an object in return then specify `[]` instead of `{}`

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Since Array.slice() does not do deep copying, it is not suitable for multidimensional arrays:

```
var a =[[1], [2], [3]];
var b = a.slice();

b.shift().shift();
// a is now [[], [2], [3]]
```

Note that although I've used `shift().shift()` above, the point is just that *`b[0][0]` contains a pointer to `a[0][0]`* rather than a value.

Likewise `delete(b[0][0])` also causes  `a[0][0]` to be deleted and `b[0][0]=99` also changes the value of `a[0][0]` to 99.

jQuery's `extend` method *does* perform a deep copy when a true value is passed as the initial argument:

```
var a =[[1], [2], [3]];
var b = $.extend(true, [], a);

b.shift().shift();
// a is still [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: Thanks Noah. Looks like my biggest problem was that I was giving $.extend and object as its first argument, not an array.

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of b.shift().shift() here?

Comment: b is just being manipulated to show that a and b don't hold the same value.  Shouldn't a and b be represented as [[3]]?  Shift removes the first value in an array entirely whether it is of any type.  It doesn't perform a recursive search for a primitive type and then remove that.  The length of an array that holds the context for the method always decreases by 1 and is edited in place.

Comment: Thank you! Your line: var b = $.extend(true, [], a); saved my life! I used $.extend(true, {}, a) braces instead of square brackets!

Comment: thanks it helped very much , normally when we copy array by direct assignment way , when one array is changed then other copied array also get changes , so this method do real copy.

Answer (score 31):

`$.extend(true, [], [['a', ['c']], 'b'])`

That should do it for you.

Comment: This will not work for multi dimensional arrays, you have to use "true" as first argument as mentioned  in answer by @Noah Sussman

Answer (score 21):

*I realize you're looking for a "deep" copy of an array, but if you just have a single level array you can use this:*

Copying a native JS Array is easy. Use the [Array.slice()](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/Ecmascript/Quickref/Slice.html) method which creates a copy of part/all of the array.

```
var foo = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var bar = foo.slice();
```

now foo and bar are 5 member arrays of 'a','b','c','d','e'

of course bar is a copy, not a reference... so if you did this next...

```
bar.push('f');
alert('foo:' + foo.join(', '));
alert('bar:' + bar.join(', '));
```

you would now get:

```
foo:a, b, c, d, e
bar:a, b, c, d, e, f
```

Comment: Note that this is not a deep copy.

Comment: similar: var a = [1,2,3];
var b = ([]).concat(a);
b is a copy

Comment: Array.slice does not provide a deep copy, which is pretty specifically  the question being asked here.

Comment: The author has put _deep_ in **parenthesis**, so any answer regarding copying is welcome. The text of the actual question doesn't even contain the word _deep_ at all.

Answer (score 13):

Everything in JavaScript is pass by reference, so if you want a true deep copy of the objects in the array, the best method I can think of is to serialize the entire array to JSON and then de-serialize it back.

Comment: Primitives are not passed by reference. Objects (incl. arrays) are, though.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use pure JavaScript then try this:

```
 var arr=["apple","ball","cat","dog"];
 var narr=[];

 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     narr.push(arr[i]);
 }
 alert(narr); //output: apple,ball,vat,dog
 narr.push("elephant");
 alert(arr); // output: apple,ball,vat,dog
 alert(narr); // apple,ball,vat,dog,elephant
```

Answer (score 3):

how about complex types?
when array contains objects... or any else

My variant:

```
Object.prototype.copy = function(){
    var v_newObj = {};
    for(v_i in this)
        v_newObj[v_i] = (typeof this[v_i]).contains(/^(array|object)$/) ? this[v_i].copy() : this[v_i];
    return v_newObj;
}

Array.prototype.copy = function(){
    var v_newArr = [];
    this.each(function(v_i){
        v_newArr.push((typeof v_i).contains(/^(array|object)$/) ? v_i.copy() : v_i);
    });
    return v_newArr;
}
```

It's not final version, just an idea.

PS: method each and contains are prototypes also.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this "deep object copy" function that I've found handy for duplicating objects by value. It doesn't use jQuery, but it certainly is deep.

http://www.overset.com/2007/07/11/javascript-recursive-object-copy-deep-object-copy-pass-by-value/

Comment: Thanks, was looking for a catch-all clone (sometimes have an object, sometimes an array of objects).

Answer (score 2):

I plan on releasing this code in the next version of [jPaq](http://jpaq.org/), but until then, you can use this if your goal is to do a deep copy of arrays:

```
Array.prototype.clone = function(doDeepCopy) {
    if(doDeepCopy) {
        var encountered = [{
            a : this,
            b : []
        }];

        var item,
            levels = [{a:this, b:encountered[0].b, i:0}],
            level = 0,
            i = 0,
            len = this.length;

        while(i < len) {
            item = levels[level].a[i];
            if(Object.prototype.toString.call(item) === "[object Array]") {
                for(var j = encountered.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if(encountered[j].a === item) {
                        levels[level].b.push(encountered[j].b);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(j < 0) {
                    encountered.push(j = {
                        a : item,
                        b : []
                    });
                    levels[level].b.push(j.b);
                    levels[level].i = i + 1;
                    levels[++level] = {a:item, b:j.b, i:0};
                    i = -1;
                    len = item.length;
                }
            }
            else {
                levels[level].b.push(item);
            }

            if(++i == len && level > 0) {
                levels.pop();
                i = levels[--level].i;
                len = levels[level].a.length;
            }
        }

        return encountered[0].b;
    }
    else {
        return this.slice(0);
    }
};
```

The following is an example of how to call this function to do a deep copy of a recursive array:

```
// Create a recursive array to prove that the cloning function can handle it.
var arrOriginal = [1,2,3];
arrOriginal.push(arrOriginal);

// Make a shallow copy of the recursive array.
var arrShallowCopy = arrOriginal.clone();

// Prove that the shallow copy isn't the same as a deep copy by showing that
// arrShallowCopy contains arrOriginal.
alert("It is " + (arrShallowCopy[3] === arrOriginal)
    + " that arrShallowCopy contains arrOriginal.");

// Make a deep copy of the recursive array.
var arrDeepCopy = arrOriginal.clone(true);

// Prove that the deep copy really works by showing that the original array is
// not the fourth item in arrDeepCopy but that this new array is.
alert("It is "
    + (arrDeepCopy[3] !== arrOriginal && arrDeepCopy === arrDeepCopy[3])
    + " that arrDeepCopy contains itself and not arrOriginal.");
```

You can play around with this code [here at JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jPaq-Array.clone/2).

Comment: Interesting. @Chris West can you say what issues that your answer addressees that jQuery extend does not? Many thanks.