# Totally basic Javascript reference question

Tags: javascript, deep-copy

The following in a Javascript console:

```
var a = {'foo': []};
var b = {};

for (var key in a) {
   b[key] = a[key];
}

a['foo'].push(1);

console.log(b);
```

Yields:

`Object foo=[1]`

I want to make a copy by value in b of each array for each key in a. Is there an easier way?

Comment: How do you get a "javascript console"?

Comment: Oscar- using Firebug inside Firefox, or Safari's Web Inspector.

Comment: @Oscar: You need FireBug for `console.log` function to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [Deep Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy). You can find examples in:

- http://www.overset.com/2007/07/11/javascript-recursive-object-copy-deep-object-copy-pass-by-value/
- [(Deep) copying an array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565430/javascript-deep-copying-an-array-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

You could make a "*clone*" function that creates a *new* object, based on the *original* object [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor), and then clone that *original* object properties also if they are objects:

```
function clone(obj){
  if(typeof(obj) != 'object' && obj != null) 
    return obj; // return the value itself if isn't an object
                // or null, since typeof  null == 'object';

    var temp = new obj.constructor();

    for(var key in obj)
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
    return temp;
}


var a = {'foo': []};
var b = clone(a);

a['foo'].push(1);

console.log(b); // Object foo=[0]
```

Comment: I ran across this problem before, and this is exactly how I solved it. +1

Comment: Prototyping breaks this. Simply `Object.prototype.foo = function () {};` will create infinite recursion.

Comment: @Jonathan: added an if statement to stop recursion.

Comment: Same problem here CMS: `obj.constructor()` is going to die on constructor functions (`temp` will be `undefined`), and potentially clobber globals.

Comment: @Crescent: Exactly, the same problem!, added the `new` operator while I think on something better...

Answer (score 0):

Easier way:

```
var a = {'foo': []};
var b = a;

a['foo'].push(1);

console.log(b);
```

Output is the same.

Edit:

```
var a = {'foo': []};
var b = {};

for (var key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        b[key] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < a[key].length; i += 1) {
            b[key][i] = a[key][i];
        }
    }
}

a['foo'].push(1);

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Anatoliy: I don't want b to simply be a reference to a; I want b to be a unique copy by value of the arrays stored in a so that when I push to a's arrays it does not affect b.

Comment: Fixed. Currently output is object with empty array.

Comment: You can simplify all of that deep-copy stuff with `a[key].slice(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

As this will add support for deep-copying arrays in your code:

```
var a = {'foo': []};
var b = {};

for (var key in a) {
   if (Object.prototype.toString.call(b[key]) === "[object Array]") {
      b[key] = a[key].slice(0);
   } else {
      b[key] = a[key];
   }
}

a['foo'].push(1);

console.log(b);
```