# jQuery Deep/Recursive Copy using $.extend

Tags: jquery

I am trying to merge two objects using jQuery $.extend.

Using the following code, I am trying to alert ( “Ball – Stump - Umpire”). But the current output is (  “Undefined – Stump - Umpire”). It does not achieve the deep (recursive) copy. How do we correct this?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        debugger;

        //$.extend
        var obj3 = { throwable: { text1: 'Ball' }, text3: 'Umpire' };
        var obj4 = { throwable: { text4: 'Bat' }, text2: 'Stump' }

        //Simple Copy
        var result1 = $.extend(obj3, obj4);
        //alert(result1.throwable.text4 + " - " + result1.text2 + " - " + result1.text3);


        //Deep Copy
        //First parameter is passed as Boolean true to accomplish deep (recursive) copy
        var result2 = $.extend(true, obj3, obj4);
        alert(result2.throwable.text1 + " - " + result2.text2 + " - " + result2.text3);


    });
```

EDIT: I referred

[(Deep) copying an array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565430/deep-copying-an-array-using-jquery)

Comment: How is **one** of those: `asp.net` `.net` `jquery-ui` `jquery-plugins` tags related to the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second code snippet does work as expected and performs a deep copy of `obj4` into `obj3`, *when run in isolation*.

The problem is, the previous code snippet has already performed a *shallow* copy of `obj4` into `obj3`, completely overriding its `throwable` member with `obj4`'s in the process. Therefore, `throwable.text1` does not exist anymore within `obj3` after that code has run.

- Initially, `obj3` is :

  ```
  { throwable: { text1: 'Ball' }, text3: 'Umpire' }
  ```
- After the first code snippet has run, `obj3` becomes :

  ```
  { throwable: { text4: 'Bat' }, text3: 'Umpire', text2: 'Slump' }
  ```
- Finally, after the second code snippet has run, `obj3` still is:

  ```
  { throwable: { text4: 'Bat' }, text3: 'Umpire', text2: 'Slump' }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `text1` property is overwritten by `extend`. I f you want a method that contacenates strings, code your own, `extend` don't do that.

Something like:

```
function(o1, o2) {
  var ores = {};
  for(var p in o1) ores.p = o1.p;
  for(var p in o2) ores.p = ores.p ? ores.p+o2.p : o2.p;
  return ores;
}
```

Comment: @Lijo if youwant to see the difference:[see](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Comment: Making a recursive merge won't concatenate srting !

Comment: So it seems to wotk now... what is the problem ?

Comment: `alert(result2.throwable.text1 +" - "+ result2.throwable.text4 + " - " + result2.text2 + " - " + result2.text3);` give me "Ball - Bat - Stump - Umpire"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that there are two properties with the same name in the objects: text1. Even with deep extends, jquery extend doesn't merge this into a new concat string or an array.

Deep copy is relevant, if one of your properties is another object. With deep extend, all properties of the child object get merged and not just the child object itself.

I think you have to go with your own extend function.