# Javascript Global Variable Scope/Overwriting on Splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have an issue I cant get to the bottom of, so any help would be much appreciated.

- A the top of my scipt I declare a global value ('`_raw`')
- (Using jQuery) I make an Ajax call, which returns JSON array data (I have
  checked, the JSON data is correct)
- I take this JSON response and assign it to `_raw`
- When I click a link, `_raw` gets passed to a function, e.g. `function myFunction(dataArray)`, called with `myFunction(_raw)`
- Within this function, based on some
  criteria, `dataArray` is spliced (i.e. `dataArray.splice(2,1)`)
- `dataArray` is then returned.

e.g.

```
var _raw;

// AJAX call sets RAW to an array e.g. Apple, Banana, Pear, Pineapple, Coconut, Raspberry

myFunction(dataArray){
  var data=dataArray;
  data.splice(2, 1);
  return data[0];
}


$('a').click(function(){

  result = myFunction(_raw);
  alert(result);
// First time this is run, returns 'Pear', however, second time, returns 'Coconut'- as if the splice is being performed on _raw as well as myArray/data...

});
```

- I appreciate there is some poor code above, this is more to illustrate the issue

The problem I have, is that as far as I can see, the only time `_raw` is set, is during the AJAX call, however, when the function myFunction is called, passing `_raw`, the splice also seems to effect `_raw` itself. Why is this happening?

Comment: arrays are passed as reference in javascript , so arrays are pointers , like objects , functions , ect ... you can use array.slice to return a new array however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, arrays are always passed by reference, so when you assign it to the data variable, you are just creating a pointer to _raw and all operations will be done on _raw.

You need to make a clone of the array. Depending what's in it and whether it's multidimensional, you may need to use a method that will do a deep copy as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565430/deep-copying-an-array-using-jquery).

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are passed by reference, so `var data = dataArray` does **not** copy the array.

So, [`data.splice(2,1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) **modifies** the original array.

Use [`.slice(2,1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to copy the array.

Or, since it seems that you want to **get** second element's value, use the numeric indices:

```
function myFunction(dataArray){
    return dataArray[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`splice()` changes the original array: see http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/slice-and-splice-in-javascript.html

> Unlike slice(), the splice() method modifies the original array and returns a new array.

As a sidenote, you don't really need to pass `_raw` as argument of `myFunction()` since it's a global variable and thus is visible everywhere