# How to create copy of an Array?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
const settings = {
            notes: [new musicnote(480,400,"wav/1.wav","cyan",true)],
            emiters: [new emiter(300,240), new emiter(340,240)]
        }

var notes = [];
var emiters = [];

var LoadLevel = function (level) {
    if(settings[level] !== undefined){
        currentLevel = level;
        notes = settings[level].notes;
        emiters = settings[level].emiters;
    }
}
```

And when I change `emiters` array in game (delete or add some) it does the same to the `settings.emiter` array. So my question is - how to pass a new array instead of a reference to array in `settings` object?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565430/deep-copying-an-array-using-jquery, and more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var original = [];
var copy = original.slice();

// to test:
copy.push("foo");
alert(original.length); // 0
```