# How to copy specific items/indexes from an Array to another Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm not a dev/programmer, I'm an accountant trying to make things easier for me, so sorry if it seems too basic or stupid.

I have an Array (fData) which has length 14 and in which index/item it has another array with length 9.

I'm iterating with it and when it meets the condition I need, I'm trying to copy each of the corresponding 9 length array elements to a newly created Array (fRetention).

I have researched a lot and used so many approaches like Array.prototype.push/apply, Push, Concat, Slice and so on.

The closest I got to what I need was using Slice, but rather than create a new index/item to the new array, it ends overwriting the fData Array and creating an Array inside an Array as per the screenshot below.

[image: fRetention Array structure]

Thanks for the help!

```
let fRetention = [];
let countret = 0;
for (var row = 0; row <= fData.length -1; row++) { //parse Array content
  if (row > 0 && row < fData.length -1) { //check for retention
  if (fData[row][0] == fData[row - 1][0] && fData[row][2] == fData[row - 1][2] &&  fData[row][1].substr(0,1) == '2' ) {
     fRetention[countret] = fData.slice(row, row + 1);
     countret ++;
```

Comment: To confirm, you want to filter `fData` and clone data from matching 9-element arrays into a single array of elements (not an array of arrays)?

Comment: In the example given, at fData[4], there are 9 matching elements, I would like to copy those to a new array and so on. So in this case, the new Array would receive 4 elements, with 9 matching elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many approaches as said, but I found a solution using this

fRetention.push (fData[row].slice(0));

Source: [For a deep copy of a JavaScript multidimensional array, going one level deep seems sufficient. Is this reliably true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100714/for-a-deep-copy-of-a-javascript-multidimensional-array-going-one-level-deep-see)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to copy just one element of fData to fRetention each time just use  the index number
so instead of doing this fRetention[countret] = fData.slice(row, row + 1);
try

```
 fRetention[countret] = fData[row];
```

if you want to get a clone of that element try :

```
 fRetention[countret] = [...fData[row]];
```

Comment: This way the fRetention ends up receiving all the elements from the fData. I only need the matching element, which the first case is fData[4] as fRetention[0] and so on... there should be at the end 4 elements in the array with 9 matching elements inside it.

Comment: that is part of you if (condition) logic, to decide which fData[row] to be copied.

I only talked about this line in your code 
"  fRetention[countret] = fData.slice(row, row + 1); "

Comment: Ok, but with this param fRetention[countret] = [...fData[row]]; , where countret = 0, row = 4 .  It was not supposed to only add the fifth element of the fData array to the '0' element of the fRetention array? Because this way it basically copied the whole array.