# What am I missing with the understanding of Arrays?

Tags: javascript

When arrays are assigned to another variable, the reference is passed as opposed to values. This is confirmed when you compare two arrays using `==` operator and it returns `true`

```
var a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
var b = a; // b = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
var c = [].concat(a); // c = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

a == b; //true
a == c; //false
```

With the above inputs, when I modify the array `b`, it mutates array `a`, but not `c`.

```
b.push([7,8]); // b = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [7,8]]
a; //a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6], [7,8]]
c; //c = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

But when I do the below, it mutates `c`.

```
b[0].push(5); // b = [[1,2,5],[3,4],[5,6], [7,8]]
a; //a = [[1,2,5],[3,4],[5,6], [7,8]]
c; //c = [[1,2,5],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Why does this happen? This behavior happens with the usage of array methods that mutates the array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) does a shallow copy. So after the line:

```
var c = [].concat(a);
```

`c` and `a` reference different arrays, but `c[0]` and `b[0]` and `a[0]` all reference the same array.

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

> *concat copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. That is, if a referenced object is modified, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.*

Comment: +1, that's the answer. Do you think it would be good idea to include how to make *deep* copy of an array (or any other object)? (jQuery `.extend()` or lodash `.deepClone()`?)

Comment: @bardzusny there's plenty of answers on stackoverflow already.

Comment: thanks nnnnnn, that explains the behavior. As @bardzusny added, could someone suggest any built in methods or libraries that does a deep copy of the arrays?

Comment: @Harish - bardzusny already mentioned two libraries that'll do a deep copy. I don't know of a native JS method that does it. Note that you have to be careful with deep copy recursive algorithms because JS allows circular references, so you can have a situation where `x===x[0]` is `true`...

Comment: In case my suggestion indeed would mean going out of the scope of the question, here's something that should satisfy you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object . Only "vanilla.js" way of easily deep-copying I can think of right off the bat is: `c = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))`, which is not perfect (you lose Date/RegEx/other "special" objects).

Comment: These links - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565430/deep-copying-an-array-using-jquery) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) gives more detail for deep copy. I am posting this for the benefit of others.