# Array of array of objects reference in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, underscore.js

I have an array as follows

```
var sample = [{a:1, b: 1, c:1}, {a:1, b: 1, c:1}, {a:1, b: 1, c:1}];
```

I then run the following code and try `groupsOfItems[0].sample[0].a = 10`,  `groupsOfItems[0].sample[0].a`, `groupsOfItems[1].sample[0].a` and `groupsOfItems[2].sample[0].a` get changed to 10.

How do I prevent this?

```js
var sample = [{a:1, b: 1, c:1}, {a:1, b: 1, c:1}, {a:1, b: 1, c:1}];


    var groupsOfItems = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var item = {};
        item.sample = _.clone(sample);
        groupsOfItems.push(item);
    }



  groupsOfItems[0].sample[0].a = 10
  
  console.log(groupsOfItems[0].sample[0].a,groupsOfItems[1].sample[0].a,groupsOfItems[2].sample[0].a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you. Please do that in the future. Saves a lot of time when testing your code

Comment: Be wary of cloning objects using libraries (or just in general). If you call a method on a cloned object the method will still be referencing the original object and will modify the original object, not the cloned object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to clone the object before assiging its referece to the array's property

Replace

```
item.sample = sample;
```

with

```
item.sample = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sample));
```

Note that this method of cloning will be less efficient when the sample object grows. Try some other methods shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object).

Comment: I did try with _.clone. Didn't help

Comment: @JaseemAbbas did you tried the method I have shared

Comment: @JaseemAbbas `_.clone()` is a *shallow copy*.  the JSON method does a *deep clone*.

Comment: _.cloneDeep() saved my day. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[as mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565430/deep-copying-an-array-using-jquery)

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var item = {};
        item.sample = $.extend(true, [], sample);
        groupsOfItems.push(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid cloning the object in general. Cloning objects only tends to end in pain further down the track. Here's how I have achieved similar in the past without cloning.

```
var sample = [{   a: 1,   b: 1,  c: 1}, {  a: 1,  b: 1,  c: 1}, {  a: 1,  b: 1,  c: 1}];
var groupsOfItems = [];

var Item = function(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var item = {};
  item.sample = _.map(sample, function(item) {
    return new Item(item.a, item.b, item.c)
  });
  groupsOfItems.push(item);
}

groupsOfItems[0].sample[0].a = 10

console.log(groupsOfItems[0].sample[0].a, groupsOfItems[1].sample[0].a, groupsOfItems[2].sample[0].a);
//10 1 1
```

This way you're assigning them all a container for your modifications and the problem with cloning goes away.